# Android memory leak testing with leak canary

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I am seeing this icon popping up many times on screen. The app is not crashing but I am getting this popup saying app will freeze for some time.

[image: Brrr! App will freeze for some time]]

Also on the log it says ...

```
In com.***.android:1.0.1:1.* FAILURE in 1.5
00f37f5:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1191492 byte allocation with 141738 free bytes and 138KB until OOM
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:118)
at com.squareup.haha.perflib.analysis.TopologicalSort$TopologicalSortVisitor.doVisit(TopologicalSort.java:92)
at com.squareup.haha.perflib.analysis.TopologicalSort.compute(TopologicalSort.java:36)
at com.squareup.haha.perflib.Snapshot.computeDominators(Snapshot.java:311)
at com.squareup.leakcanary.HeapAnalyzer.findLeakTrace(HeapAnalyzer.java:187)
at com.squareup.leakcanary.HeapAnalyzer.checkForLeak(HeapAnalyzer.java:122)
at com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.HeapAnalyzerService.onHandleIntent(HeapAnalyzerService.java:58)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)* 
Reference Key: 010554da-4ffc-41c4-b0b3-ee5d12989a31* 
Device: Xiaomi Xiaomi 2014818 2014818* 
Android Version: 5.1.1
API: 22
LeakCanary: 1.5 00f37f5*
Durations: watch=5829ms, gc=202ms, heap dump=4019ms, analysis=292701ms*
Excluded Refs:|
Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mNextServedView|
Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedView|
Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mServedInputConnection|
Field: android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.mCurRootView|
Field: android.animation.LayoutTransition$1.val$parent
Field: android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession$1.this$0
Field: android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserModel.mActivityChoserModelPolicy
Field: android.widget.ActivityChooserModel.mActivityChoserModelPolicy
Field: android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.this$1
Field: android.media.MediaScannerConnection.mContext
Field: android.os.UserManager.mContext
Field: android.media.AudioManager$1.this$0
Field: android.widget.Editor$Blink.this$0
Field: android.net.ConnectivityManager.sInstance
Field: android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.mMessageQueue (always)
Static field: android.text.TextLine.sCached
Thread:FinalizerWatchdogDaemon (always)
Thread:main (always)
Thread:LeakCanary-Heap-Dump (always)
Class:java.lang.ref.WeakReference (always)
Class:java.lang.ref.SoftReference (always)
Class:java.lang.ref.PhantomReference (always)
Class:java.lang.ref.Finalizer (always)
Class:java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference (always)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a memory leak detected by [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary).

[Here](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/wiki/FAQ) are some frequently asked question about LeakCanary